# Unable to render element using Ajax using php in wordpress template

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I was trying to replace element through ajax call but error is coming here is my code

script.js

```
jQuery(document).on('change','.joinee-filter-month',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var category=jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.log(category);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data:{action:'month_filter',category:category},
            success:function(response)
            {
                jQuery('.rowAppend').html(response);
            },
            error:function(response)
            {
                console.log("function not working");
            }

        })
```

function.php

```
 function joinee_month_filter_function()
    {
            ?>
            <div>hello</div>
            <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_month_filter', 'joinee_month_filter_function');
```

error: function not working

Answer (score 0):

in `function.php` make sure that you call the function for logged-in/guest user

For non-users

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/

For users

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/

```
function joinee_month_filter_function()
{
        ?>
        <div>hello</div>
        <?php
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_month_filter", "joinee_month_filter_function");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_month_filter", "joinee_month_filter_function");
```

Also this is tutorial How to use ajax in Wordpress
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: what is the issue you face?

Comment: when leave the function in function.php empty my ajax show no error but on returning something it gives an error

Comment: then it works but the issue in code function in function.php, Can you show me the function to check it